# Custom Tabs using react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have created custom tabs in react-native but I am unable to select a tab. I have initialized the state for the selected tab but do not know where to set the state.

here is my code:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var windowSize = Dimensions.get('window');
var bg = require('image!bg');

class TabView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'list',
      selectedTab: 'map'
    };
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.bg} source={bg} />
        <View style={styles.tabView}>
          <View style={[styles.listView,styles.selectedView]}>
            <Text>List View</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.listView,{}]}>
            <Text>Map View</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  bg: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: windowSize.width,
        height: windowSize.height
    },
  tabView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    //bottom: 200,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'rgba(4, 193, 3,1)',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginTop: 50
  },
  listView: {
    flex: 2,
    padding:7,
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  mapView: {
    flex: 2,
    padding:7,
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  selectedView: {
    backgroundColor:'rgba(4, 193, 3,1)',
    color: 'white'
  }
});

module.exports = TabView
```

I just want to know where shall I add a check so that I can make a difference in the selected tab

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check out the code here, to get an idea how it can be done

```
const Tab = (props) => {
  let style = props.isSelected && styles.selectedTab || styles.normalTab;

  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.onTabPress(props.id)}>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  )
}


class TabsView extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'one'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Tab onTabPress={this.onSelectTab.bind(this)} title="One" id="one" isSelected={this.state.selectedTab == "one"}/>
         <Tab onTabPress={this.onSelectTab.bind(this)} title="Two" id="two" isSelected={this.state.selectedTab == "two"}/>
      </View>
    )
  }

  onSelectTab(selectedTab) {
    this.setState({ selectedTab })
  }
}
```

The above code splits your component in two parts, a logical part (TabsView) and a dumb presentational part (Tab)

The logical handles the clickHandler (onSelectTab) which is passed as a prop (onTabPress) to the dumb (Tab) Component.

Comment: nice to hear that ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know where shall I add a check so that I can make a difference in the selected tab

In the `render` method, it should go

example:

```
render() {
  let FirstTabStyles = Object.assign(
      defaultTabStyles,
      (isFirstSelected && selectedStyles || {})
  )

  let SecondTabStyle = Object.assign(
      defaultTabStyles,
      (isSecondSelected && selectedStyles || {})
  )

  return (
     <View>
       <FirstTab style={FirstTabStyle} />
       <SecondTab style={SecondTabStyle} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: that i know, I am asking what should I write their

Comment: what check shall I provide in this.state.selectedtab?

Comment: I don't know it depend on your logic, its up to you

Comment: I'll write a new answer

Comment: confused actually!

Comment: my goal is that I want to set a state so that if  select a tab then it will show me the style of list view otherwise it should display the style of map view. I have already defined their styles

Comment: please check out my other answer which has a finished example, with setters and so on